# Cannot read property 'Injectable' of undefined Angular

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// format of Product Interface so typing mistakes will be avoided
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()

export class ProductService {
    private _productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';
    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get( this._productUrl )
            .map( (response: Response) => <IProduct[]>response.json() )
            .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }

    private handleErrors(error: Response){
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }

}
```

Injectable imported on top of file but getting error in Chrome dev tools
Check the Chrome Developer Tool image below

[Injectable Undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktBxL.jpg)

Comment: You are being mislead by the error message, it seems the error is caused in product-list.component

Comment: Don't know if it's significant, but try removing blank line between @Injectable and export...

Comment: Service code looks good. Most likely the problem is in your component (that length related is a tip). Could you provide more code of your component?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the import statements for the Observable operators. Try adding this to the top by your other import statements.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: I assume you are working through my Pluralsight course? On the Pluralsight page there is an Exercise Files tab. If you click that tab you can download all of the course files as a zip file. There is a folder in the zip file for each module of the course. You could then use a file compare utility to compare your files to the files in the module you are currently on.